# Find out if a list of strings contains permutations of words from another string (counter for each combination)

Tags: c#, .net, string

I didn't know exactly how to ask this question better so I will try to explain it as best as I can.

Let's say I have one list of 20 strings `myList1<string>` and I have another string `string ToCompare`. Now each of the strings in the list as well as the `string ToCompare` have 8 words divided by empty spaces. I want to know how many times combination of any three words from `string ToCompare` in any possible order is to be found in the strings of `myList1<string>`. For an example:

This is the list (short version - example):

```
string1 = "AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH";
string2 = "BB DD EE AA HH II JJ MM";
.......
string20 = "NN OO AA RR EE BB FF KK";

string ToCompare = "BB GG AA FF CC MM RR II";
```

Now I want to know how many times any combination of 3 words from `ToCompare` string is to be found in `myList1<string>`. To clarify futher three words from `ToCompare` `"BB AA CC"` are found in `string1` of the list thus the counter for these 3 words would be 1. Another 3 words from `ToCompare` `"BB AA II"` are found in the `string2` of `myList1<string>` but the counter here would be also 1 because it's not the same combination of words (I have `"AA"` and `"BB"` but also `"II"`. They are not equal). Order of these 3 words doesn't matter, that means `"AA BB CC" = "BB AA CC" = "CC BB AA"`. I want to know how many combinations of all (any) 3 words from `ToCompare` are found in `myList1<string>`. I hope it's clear what I mean.

Any help would be appreciated, I don't have a clue how to solve this. Thanks.

Example from Vanest:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>();
            source.Add("2 4 6 8 10 12 14 99");
            source.Add("16 18 20 22 24 26 28 102");
            source.Add("33 6 97 38 50 34 87 88");
```

string ToCompare = "2 4 6 15 20 22 28 44";

The rest of the code is exacty the same, and the result:

```
Key = 2 4 6, Value = 2
Key = 2 4 20, Value = 1
Key = 2 4 22, Value = 1
Key = 2 4 28, Value = 1
Key = 2 6 20, Value = 1
Key = 2 6 22, Value = 1
Key = 2 6 28, Value = 1
Key = 2 20 22, Value = 1
Key = 2 20 28, Value = 1
Key = 2 22 28, Value = 1
Key = 4 6 20, Value = 1
Key = 4 6 22, Value = 1
Key = 4 6 28, Value = 1
Key = 4 20 22, Value = 1
Key = 4 20 28, Value = 1
Key = 4 22 28, Value = 1
Key = 6 20 22, Value = 1
Key = 6 20 28, Value = 1
Key = 6 22 28, Value = 1
Key = 20 22 28, Value = 1
```

As you can see there are combinations which not exist in the strings, and the value of the first combination is 2 but it comes only one time in the first string

Comment: Start by breaking down the problem into smaller ones: a) you need a way to generate all "three-word-groups" from `ToCompare`. If you got that b) you need a way to check if a "three-word-group" is contained in a string. Then c) count by how may strings it's contained. As it stands, the question is too broad for Stack Overflow. This site is for _specific_ programming problems. So start solving smaller parts of the problem and ask when you got stuck on a _specific_ problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you're asking for:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = 
        new List<String> 
        {
            "AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH",
            "BB DD EE AA HH II JJ MM",
            "NN OO AA RR EE BB FF KK"
        };

    var toCompare = "BB GG AA FF CC MM RR II";

    var permutations = CountPermutations(list, toCompare);
}

public Int32 CountPermutations(List<String> list, String compare)
{
    var words = compare.Split(' ');

    return list
        .Select(l => l.Split(' '))
        .Select(l => new { String = String.Join(" ", l), Count = l.Join(words, li => li, wi => wi, (li, wi) => li).Count()})
        .Sum(x => x.Count - 3);
}
```

[edit: 2/20/2019]

You can use the following to get all the matches to each list item with the total number of unique combinations

```
void Main()
{
    var list =
        new List<String>
        {
            "AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH",
            "BB DD EE AA HH II JJ MM",
            "NN OO AA RR EE BB FF KK",
            "AA AA CC DD EE FF GG HH"
        };

    list.Select((l, i) => new { Index = i, Item = l }).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"List Item{x.Index + 1}: {x.Item}"));

    var toCompare = "BB GG AA FF CC MM RR II";

    Console.WriteLine($"To Compare: {toCompare}");

    Func<Int32, Int32> Factorial = x => x < 0 ? -1 : x == 0 || x == 1 ? 1 : Enumerable.Range(1, x).Aggregate((c, v) => c * v);

    var words = toCompare.Split(' ');

    var matches = list
        // Get a list of the list items with all their parts
        .Select(l => new { Parts = l.Split(' '), Original = l })
        // Join each part from the to-compare item to each part of the list item
        .Select(l => new { String = String.Join(" ", l), Matches = l.Parts.Join(words, li => li, wi => wi, (li, wi) => li), l.Original })
        // Only consider items with at least 3 matches
        .Where(l => l.Matches.Count() >= 3)
        // Get the each item including how many parts matched and how many unique parts there are of each part
        .Select(l => new { l.Original, Matches = String.Join(" ", l.Matches), Count = l.Matches.Count(), Groups = l.Matches.GroupBy(m => m).Select(m => m.Count()) })
        // To calculate the unique combinations for each match use the following mathematical equation: match_count! / (frequency_part_1! * frequency_part_2! * ... * frequency_part_n!)
        .Select(l => new { l.Original, l.Matches, Combinations = Factorial(l.Count) / l.Groups.Aggregate((c, v) => c * Factorial(v)) })
        .ToList();

    matches.ForEach(m => Console.WriteLine($"Original: {m.Original}, Matches: {m.Matches}, Combinations: {m.Combinations}"));

    var totalUniqueCombinations = matches.Sum(x => x.Combinations);

    Console.WriteLine($"Total Unique Combinations: {totalUniqueCombinations}");

}
```

Comment: this does not maintain any word combination corresponding to the count I guess.

Comment: I don't think I understand the word combination correspondence requirement. Will  you please explain so I can attempt to include this in my solution?

Comment: I meant to say that your code produces just an integer with no clues to the word combinations which derived the count. For ex, Combination1 = "BB AA FF", Count = 2
                      Combination2 = "BB GG AA", Count = 1,   etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should suffice your ask,

```
List<string> source = new List<string>();
source.Add("AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH");
source.Add("BB DD EE AA HH II JJ MM");
source.Add("NN OO AA RR EE BB FF KK");

string ToCompare = "BB GG AA FF CC MM RR II";

string word1, word2, word3, existingKey;
string[] compareList = ToCompare.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Dictionary<string, int> ResultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < compareList.Length - 2; i++)
{
    word1 = compareList[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < compareList.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        word2 = compareList[j];
        for (int z = j + 1; z < compareList.Length; z++)
        {
            word3 = compareList[z];
            source.ForEach(x =>
            {
                if (x.Contains(word1) && x.Contains(word2) && x.Contains(word3))
                {
                    existingKey = ResultDictionary.Keys.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Contains(word1) && y.Contains(word2) && y.Contains(word3));
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingKey))
                    {
                        ResultDictionary.Add(word1 + " " + word2 + " " + word3, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ResultDictionary[existingKey]++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`ResultDictionary` will have the 3 word combinations that occur in `myList1<string>` with their count of occurrences. To get the total count, retrieve and add all the value fields from `ResultDictionary`.

EDIT:

Below snippet produces correct result with the given input,

```
List<string> source = new List<string>();
source.Add("2 4 6 8 10 12 14 99");
source.Add("16 18 20 22 24 26 28 102");
source.Add("33 6 97 38 50 34 87 88");

string ToCompare = "2 4 6 15 20 22 28 44";

string word1, word2, word3, existingKey;
string[] compareList = ToCompare.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] sourceList, keywordList;
Dictionary<string, int> ResultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
source.ForEach(x =>
{
    sourceList = x.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < compareList.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        word1 = compareList[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < compareList.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            word2 = compareList[j];
            for (int z = j + 1; z < compareList.Length; z++)
            {
                word3 = compareList[z];
                if (sourceList.Contains(word1) && sourceList.Contains(word2) && sourceList.Contains(word3))
                {
                    existingKey = ResultDictionary.Keys.FirstOrDefault(y =>
                                  {
                                      keywordList = y.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                                      return keywordList.Contains(word1) && keywordList.Contains(word2) && keywordList.Contains(word3);
                                  });
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingKey))
                    {
                        ResultDictionary.Add(word1 + " " + word2 + " " + word3, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ResultDictionary[existingKey]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks @Vanest, your solution goues in the right direction but it's not giving correct results. I attached (edited my post) an example with your solution and the result, as you can see the values are not right.

Comment: @user3613744 kindly use the updated snippet which produces correct result